# MongoDB 3.4 collation in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

MongoDB 3.4 has the collation function, which can be used in find, like so:

```
db.myCollection.find({city: "new york"}).collation({locale: "en", strength: 2});
```

Could be too new, but is there any way to do a find query using collation in PHP? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `collation` as option parameter to `.find()`

```
$result = $collection->find(
    [], 
    [ 
        'collation' => [ 
            'locale' => 'en', 
            'strength' => 2 
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, I put this in the same array as the one that lists all the fields I want returned? so it would be [_id => 1, field_id => 1, collation => [ .... ] ]

Right?

Comment: Doing this:
`array('projection' => array('fields' => 1), 'collation' => array('locale' => 'en', 'strength' => 2))`

Gets me the following error: 
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'localhost:27017: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue: Unsupported projection option: projection: { fields: 1 }'`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [It should work](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-find/#phpmethod.MongoDB\Collection::find)

Comment: Removing "projection" also generates an error... `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'localhost:27017: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue: >1 field in obj: { locale: "en", strength: 2 }'`